# What matches this regex: qr/(?!)/;

Tags: regex, perl

In one source code I found this regex:

```
qr/(?!)/;
```

I simply can't figure out what this matches.

Honestly, absolutely don't understand what means the *A zero-width negative look-ahead assertion.* - what i found in the perlre. :(

Can someone explain it in an human language, please? :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is legal, but matches nothing at all.

The `(?!...)` construct is a *negative lookahead assertion*. In details, it means: "match a position where the regex that follows (`...`) should *not* match the input string".

But in this case, the "regex that follows" is the empty regex, which matches everything.

So, this regex essentially says "match a position where what follows cannot be matched by the empty regex"... And there can be no such position, whatever the input string. This is a regex construct which always fails!

Comment: Don't want lie - so can't say: Ahh, fully understand now. But, your explanation gives me some light into the total darkness. Thank you. :) accept.

Comment: I can give more details on demand ;) In particular, what an _anchor_ in a regex means. If you want, I can give a full, more detailed explanation into the inner working of anchors ;)

Answer (score 25):

The empty regex pattern matches a zero-length string, which is to say it always matches. It's an obvious progression:

```
'bbbbb' =~ /^(?:aaa|bbb)/   # Matches (Matches 3 "b"s, from pos 0 to 3)
'bbbbb' =~ /^(?:aaa|bb)/    # Matches (Matches 2 "b"s, from pos 0 to 2)
'bbbbb' =~ /^(?:aaa|b)/     # Matches (Matches 1 "b",  from pos 0 to 1)
'bbbbb' =~ /^(?:aaa|)/      # Matches (Matches 0 "b"s, from pos 0 to 0)
```

This means that `(?=)` ("Is this position followed by a zero-length string?") always matches and `(?!)` ("Is this position not followed by a zero-length string?") never matches. In fact, `(?!)` is optimised to `(*FAIL)` since the latter's introduction in 5.10.

`(?!)` aka `(*FAIL)` is useful to force backtracking when the pattern has side-effects.

```
'abcd' =~ /(.+?)(?{ print "$1\n" })(?!)/;
```

Output:

```
a
ab
abc
abcd
b
bc
bcd
c
cd
d
```

---

Explanation of example:

`(?!)` doesn't match, so the regex engine keeps trying to find a match by having `.+?` match more and more characters. When that fails, the regex engine tries to match at a later starting position.

This is called "backtracking". It's how the regex engine can match `'aaaab' =~ /a*ab/`. The first time through, `a*` matches all 4 `a`s, so the `ab` doesn't match, so the engine backtracks. The second time through, `a*` only matches 3 of the `a`s, allowing `ab` and thus the whole pattern to match.

The step by step flow for the example I originally gave follows:

1. Start matching at pos 0.
2. `(.+?)` matches `a` at pos 0
3. `(?{ print "$1\n" })` prints `a` and matches zero chars
4. `(?!)` doesn't match. ⇒ Backtrack!
5. `(.+?)` matches `ab` at pos 0
6. `(?{ print "$1\n" })` prints `ab` and matches zero chars
7. `(?!)` doesn't match. ⇒ Backtrack!
8. `(.+?)` matches `abc` at pos 0
9. `(?{ print "$1\n" })` prints `abc` and matches zero chars
10. `(?!)` doesn't match. ⇒ Backtrack!
11. `(.+?)` matches `abcd` at pos 0
12. `(?{ print "$1\n" })` prints `abcd` and matches zero chars
13. `(?!)` doesn't match. ⇒ Backtrack!
14. `(.+?)` can't match anything else here. ⇒ Backtrack!
15. Start matching at pos 1.
16. `(.+?)` matches `b` at pos 1
17. `(?{ print "$1\n" })` prints `b` and matches zero chars
18. `(?!)` doesn't match. ⇒ Backtrack!
19. ...
20. `(.+?)` matches `d` at pos 3
21. `(?{ print "$1\n" })` prints `d` and matches zero chars
22. `(?!)` doesn't match. ⇒ Backtrack!
23. `(.+?)` can't match anything else here. ⇒ Backtrack!
24. Start matching at pos 4.
25. `(.+?)` doesn't match. ⇒ Backtrack!
26. Pattern doesn't match.

Comment: I need learn much much more to be able understand the example. I understand the `(.+?)` = match the shortest possible string and add it to the capture-group, understand the `push...`, but haven't any idea why it is repeats - so why gives the above result. I'm a beginner only - but thank you. ;)

Comment: `(?!)` doesn't match, so the regex engine keeps trying to find a match by having `.+?` match more characters. When that fails, the regex engine tries to match at a later starting position. This is called "backtracking". It's how the regex engine can match `'aaaab' =~ /a*ab/`. The first time through, `a*` matches all 5 `a`s, so the `ab` doesn't match, so it backtracks. The second time through, `a*` only matches 4 `a`s, allowing `ab` to match.

Comment: ... and I thought I knew regex

Comment: @kizzx2, Well, that's the theoretical view of things. Implementation generally have many optimisations.

Comment: For historical interest, `(*FAIL)` wasn't always there; `(?!)` worked at least a decade earlier :)

Answer (score 1):

`(?=)`, an empty *positive* lookahead, will always match. It’s a hackish way to set the value of the last successful match. `(?!)` is its inverse, and will never match.